# Android issue with certificate types

Tags: android, certificate

I need certificates for signing PDF files in Android app. Seems like I can sign them using only pfx or p12 types (in iText).
What I have till now:

1. Android app generates Certificate Signing Request to the server;
2. The server returns certificate data in the form of

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

The server returns X509 certificate which I cannot use to sign PDFs. Is there a way to convert from cer (which is constructed from above data) to p12? Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In general, to digitally sign a document **you need a private key and a certificate** (and probably the certification chain), and you have both:

- **The private key** is used to sign the Certificate Signing Request sent to server (which includes some certificate data like `CN` and the public key)
- **The certificate** (and probably the chain) is returned by server

I am not expert in itext, but you can see in [this example](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-12) that the signature is done with private key and the chain. The pkcs12 keystore is only used to extract the key and the chain.

```
public void signPdfFirstTime(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
    String path = properties.getProperty("PRIVATE");
    String keystore_password = properties.getProperty("PASSWORD");
    String key_password = properties.getProperty("PASSWORD");
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "BC");
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(path), keystore_password.toCharArray());
    String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, key_password.toCharArray());
    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
    // reader and stamper
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
    // appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper .getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setImage(Image.getInstance(RESOURCE));
    appearance.setReason("I've written this.");
    appearance.setLocation("Foobar");
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(72, 732, 144, 780), 1,    "first");
    // digital signature
    ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256", "BC");
    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
}
```

Comment: hello, by writing certificate, do you mean public part, which is .cer?

Comment: Yes, the certificate is the public part. A .cer file contains a certificate

Answer (score 0):

i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765842/android-sign-data-with-p12-certificate). hope it helps

```
        String password = "password";
        String text = "545048";
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        InputStream inputStream = activity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.am_client);
        keyStore.load(inputStream, password.toCharArray());

        String alias = keyStore.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)keyStore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)keyStore.getCertificate(alias);

        //Sign Data
        byte[] dataToSign = text.getBytes("UTF-8"); //change to UTF-16 if needed
        Signature signature1 = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA");
        signature1.initSign(privateKey);
        signature1.update(dataToSign);
        byte[] signedData = signature1.sign();
        String signed = new String(signedData, "UTF-8"); //change to UTF-16 if needed
        Log.d("MESSAGE", "string = " + signed);
```